# Swiper image slider - how to center images inside a slide?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, swiper.js

I am developing an Ionic/Angular application and have to show an image slider. I did this with swiper ([https://swiperjs.com/get-started#install-from-npm]). Now my slides look like this (images have different widths and heights):
[actual looking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yluKd.jpg)

My question is: Is there a way to center these images horizontally and vertically? This would be so much better looking!
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you add your code example? Create simple Code Snippet with markups/scripts/styles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of ​​swiperjs is to turn the entire div into a slider slider. You can do whatever layout you want inside that div. My advice is to design it separately, with some tool and then add it to the div with the swiper-slide class.